# Creating a single Vue component inside a larger project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have a PHP project that uses Kirby CMS. I also use Gulp for building my assets. Now, I need to add a calculator on the homepage that is complex enough to justify the usage of Vue. How would I incorporate Vue in my project without introducing a ton of new tooling? All I want is a simple Single File Component basically. I have:

```
<div id="calculator"></div>
```

and I want the component to be rendered there. Nothing more.

After some consideration, I came up with the following options but found issues with each of them:

1. Use the [Vue CLI for instant prototyping](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/prototyping.html). That's the closest solution for my use case, but I can't easily develop the component. If I use `vue serve`, I get to see the component isolated in a new page. The issue lies in the fact the component isn't a part of my project's page. It's not affected by its stylesheets, layout, and other scripts. I can't know if it'll work properly once I build it and view it in my project. Running `vue build` on each change would be pretty painful and time consuming. Sadly, `vue watch` isn't a thing, which leads me to:
2. Creating a project and using [Vue CLI Service](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build). If I create a project, I'd be able to run `vue-cli-service build --watch` and have my component automatically refresh on each change of its source file. While developing the component, I simply make a change, wait for it to compile, and refresh my project in the browser to see the modified component in action. While that would work, it introduces a bunch of `node_modules` inside my project, along with a `package.json`. I feel that's too much for just a single component. It would pollute the project more than I'd like:

   ```
   assets/
     js/
       build/
       calculator/
         dist/
         node_modules/  # modules here
         public/        # I don't need that
         package.json   # package here
         package-lock.json
         App.vue
       scripts/
       main.js
   content/
   site/
   node_modules/  # modules here as well
   panel/
   package.json   # package here as well
   package-lock.json
   index.php
   ```

   I would basically have a project within a project.
3. Use [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify) to compile the component with Browserify and Gulp (which I already use). While this appears OK, vueify is deprecated and not supported. Besides, I'd have to add a bunch of stuff to my `gulpfile.js` in order to use Babel + ESLint for the component.

---

How do I set up Vue in such a way that I'm able to develop a very simple component as a part of a larger project with as little friction as possible?

If anyone has dealt with a similar problem, how did they solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for but if I were you I'd look into [inline templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Inline-Templates) and [x-templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates) as they seem well suited to your use case.

Also have a look at this [blog post](https://medium.com/js-dojo/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs-c04e0c72900d). It offers a nice write up about the different template authoring methods in Vue and their pros/cons.

Comment: Inline templates didn't come to my mind initially. I believe I figured it out, though (you can check my answer). Also, thanks for the useful link.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the second approach I mentioned in my question with one small twist - I initialized the Vue project in my main project. I merged them.

1. I opened the parent folder of my project in a terminal.
2. I ran `vue create my-project` where `my-project` was the actual folder name of my project. The CLI asked if it should overwrite the project or merge it. I chose merge.
3. After the project was created, my old `package.json` was overwritten and only had the Vue dependencies listed in it.
4. I reverted my old `package.json` and installed these packages: `@vue/cli-plugin-babel`, `@vue/cli-service`, `vue-template-compiler`, and `vue`.
5. I added the following npm script in my `package.json`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "calculator": "vue-cli-service build assets/js/calculator/main.js --watch --dest assets/js/calculator/build"
   }
   ```

### Result

My project's folder structure remained the same, except for a few new packages in `node_modules`. I put my component files in `assets/js/calculator/`. There, I have `main.js` which is the main component script, and `build` which is a folder containing the processed component.

I have:

```
<div id="calculator"></div>
```

in my page, and:

```
<script src="/assets/js/calculator/build/app.js"></script>
```

in the footer. When I open the page, the component is rendered correctly.

To modify the component, I simply run `npm run calculator` in a terminal, which spins up the CLI service. It monitors the `main.js` file and builds the component on each change. Once the build is complete (which happens in under a second), I refresh the page and the updated component is there.

### Conclusion

I believe that's the smoothest way to handle this use case. It didn't bloat the project, all dependencies were listed, and the development experience is great. The part where my `package.json` got overwritten was a bit concerning, but other than that - it worked perfectly. If there's a better way to do this, please leave an answer!